# v-for within component template

Tags: vuejs2

Im trying to loop through an array of objects within the template of a vue component but it keeps saying that the for loop value is not defined and i cant figure out why, if i output something other then the value it will loop the correct number of times so that means it must be accessing the array ok yet if i try to output that key in the loop it will say undefined

```
Vue.options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];

window.search = {
    selected : 'all',
    salePrices : [
        {
            name: 'any price',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 99999999999,
            selected: true
        },
        {
            name: '£50k - 200k',
            minValue: 50000,
            maxValue: 200000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£200k - £400k',
            minValue: 200000,
            maxValue: 400000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£600k - £800k',
            minValue: 600000,
            maxValue: 800000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£800k +',
            minValue: 800000,
            maxValue: 9999999999999,
            selected: false
        }
    ]
}

var filter = Vue.component('property-filter', {
    template: `
        <div class="filter-container">
            <div class="type-sort">
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected = 'sales'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn' 
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'sales' }"
                >sales</a>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected='lettings'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn'
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'lettings' }"
                >lettings</a>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected='openViewings'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn'
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'openViewings' }"
                >open viewings</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sales-price-sort" v-if="search.selected == 'sales'">
                <div v-for="(value, key) in search.salePrices" :key="key">
                    <a class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn">${value.name}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {

    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            key: '',
            search: window.search
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why this happens yet. but first, you should [deep clone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep) `window.search` when using it in data. Other wise, editing search will edit window.search as well. using lodash, `search: _.cloneDeep(window.search)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the delimiters.

You specify `${...}` as the delimiters:

```js
Vue.options.delimiters = ['${', '}'];
```

But the syntax `${...}` has special meaning in template strings.

So `${value.name}` in the template below is actually picking up a `value` global variable (which doesn't exist):

```js
var filter = Vue.component('property-filter', {
    template: `
        ...
        <a class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn">${value.name}</a>
        ...
    `, //                                                  -------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Solution** is just to **change the delimiter**.

Example (using `@{...}`):

```js
Vue.options.delimiters = ['@{', '}'];

var filter = Vue.component('property-filter', {
    template: `
        ...
        <a class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn">@{value.name}</a>
        ...
    `,
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.options.delimiters = ['@{', '}'];

window.search = {
    selected : 'all',
    salePrices : [
        {
            name: 'any price',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 99999999999,
            selected: true
        },
        {
            name: '£50k - 200k',
            minValue: 50000,
            maxValue: 200000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£200k - £400k',
            minValue: 200000,
            maxValue: 400000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£600k - £800k',
            minValue: 600000,
            maxValue: 800000,
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: '£800k +',
            minValue: 800000,
            maxValue: 9999999999999,
            selected: false
        }
    ]
}

var filter = Vue.component('property-filter', {
    template: `
        <div class="filter-container">
            <div class="type-sort">
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected = 'sales'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn' 
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'sales' }"
                >sales</a>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected='lettings'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn'
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'lettings' }"
                >lettings</a>
                <a href="" @click.prevent="search.selected='openViewings'" class='uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn main-btn'
                    v-bind:class="{ selected : search.selected == 'openViewings' }"
                >open viewings</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sales-price-sort" v-if="search.selected == 'sales'">
                <div v-for="(value, key) in search.salePrices" :key="key">
                    <a class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large purple-btn">@{value.name}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {

    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            key: '',
            search: window.search
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Click 'sales'.
  <property-filter></property-filter>
</div>
```